# Is there a way we can list personal access token in laravel for admin

Tags: laravel, personal-access-token

I have integrated the Personal Access token for the API Users.

Also i have some third party users on my app. so i have created a tokens for them for long time expiration.

So how can i list the Token with their expiration date time in laravel

In guide i have seen method to get tokens for users

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#get-oauthpersonal-access-tokens

```
GET /oauth/personal-access-tokens
```

But it says Route 404 Not Found

So is there any way to list the Tokens of users
as our clients wants every token to be listed with its expiration date and time.

Comment: Are you using laravel sanctum?

Comment: No i am using laravel/passport

Comment: Opps, I missed the line. Sorry

Comment: Have you missed an installation step as that route should not return a 404. Is the route listed in `php artisan route:list`?